# TextFieldParser Delimiters value not recognized correctly

Tags: vb.net

I have some simply problem i guess, if you see below statments work without the last one: ValueFromTextFile which its value comming from my text file. This value in text file is exactly the same: "vbTab" - however it looks like when i trying to get it from my text file its not recognized the same as first line {vbTab} from example. Why is that?

```
.Delimiters = New String() {vbTab}     <- this works
.Delimiters = New String() {","}       <- this works
.Delimiters = New String() {ValueFromTextFile}     <- this doesn't work
```

**EDIT: (helper delimeter class):**

```
Public Class CharDelimeterHelper

    Private _delimeter As String
    Public Sub New(ByVal delimeter As String)
        Me._delimeter = delimeter
    End Sub

    Function GetDelimeterFormat() As ??
        Dim result As ??

        Select Case _delimeter
            Case "vbTab"
                result = ControlChars.Tab
            Case ","
                result = ","
            Case Else

        End Select

        Return result
    End Function

End Class
```

Comment: The string `"vbTab"` is not the same as the constant [`vbTab`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.constants.vbtab%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

The string `"vbTab"` is not the same as the constant [`vbTab`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.constants.vbtab%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

So if `ValueFromTextFile` equals `"vbTab"` is only works if all fields are separated by the string `"vbTab"` which i strongly doubt. I guess that they are separated by the tab-character which is represented by the `vbTab`-constant. You could also use [`ControlChars.Tab`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.controlchars.tab.aspx).

Comment: i noticed that therefore. My delimeters comming out from xml serialized document for each report that's why i am trying to initiate delimeter helper class to get correct format of delimeter passed from given xml but in fact i am not sure what should be return type of my GetDelimeterFormat function and result. Can you check and support me here? Check my first editem post.

Comment: @unknown: i must admit that i don't understand the use of your class. Why do you need it? However, the return type should be `String`.

Comment: because if i put it like that: .Delimiters = New String() {ValueFromTextFile} and in fact ValueFromTextFile is string comming from xml serialized file and this will be not working, thats the reason why first i want to pass ValueFromTextFile to this helper class and be converted to ControlChars.Tab. you see what i mean?

Comment: You could also store the `vbTab` in the text-file, so the actual tab character(which is invisible).

Comment: i have "vbTab" in xml serialized config file which from there it is taking to ValueFromTextFile if the reports is tab delimeted.

Comment: If you just want to be able to convert the string "vbTab" to an actual tab character, then just change ?? to String in your GetDelimiterFormat function. You might also want to add `result = _delimiter` to your Case Else clause. Note that you don't really need a class for this, you could just have a GetDelimiterFormat function that accepts the value from the text file as an argument and returns the desired delimiter ("," ControlChars.Tab, or whatever).